# Array value in imagestring

Tags: php

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/uBaMn.png');
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
imagestring($img, 1, 20, 21, $f['5'], $color);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
<?php 
$url = "http://2006scape.com/services/hiscores/index_lite.ws?player1=boardwalk";
    $f = explode(",", file_get_contents($url));
    print_r($f);
?>
```

Notice the : $f['5']

I'm trying to echo out array 5, but it doesnt work, because it needs to be in a double quote or single quote, but if i do that, it echo out exactly: "$f['5']".

Comment: i don't even see $f defined until you hit the explode? you can't use it before it's declared.. or your example is wrong.

Comment: I am not following here, why is you code that populates `$f` after where `$f` is actually being used?  IF you are truly intending to use the array `$f` build via `explode` you need to have this code first and you should  reference the 6th item in the array as `$f[5]` (no quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the position of your code

```
$url = "http://2006scape.com/services/hiscores/index_lite.ws?player1=boardwalk";
$f = explode(",", file_get_contents($url));


header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$img = imagecreatefrompng('http://i.imgur.com/uBaMn.png');
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
imagestring($img, 5, 220, 6, "F5 : " . $f['5'], $color);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Output

[image]